# TypeScript - Getting all ancestors - Type (...) is missing the following properties from type (...) pop, push, concat, join, and 24 more

Tags: typescript

I have flat list of node items. Every item have `id` and `parentId`. However I would like have function which returns array of every related (ancestors) items + "selected" item itself.

I wrote function with typed everything. Function works great, but TypeScript still complaining about

```
Type '(items: Items, id: number) => any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Item[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 24 more.
```

I don't understand the problem. Whole solution is below. [Live editor.](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-hooks-nwoj1?file=/src/index.ts) | [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnLAAmAXMiAK4YBG0A3PsgA5xQTiqnlW1TIA+3ADZCGAX1y4wATyYp0EDAGdkAXjSYA2gF0GuBAHsQSsMggAPOBiZCIC5WXsr1mxgHo3yAEoGDpiLYY7GCM2IRcAIwANMyswZxklCLIYlGSBB7IAMIAFsBCRGwgyAYwyBGh4WQATDEsRWAJ5SlpBGHEZADMdXEckS2VHcgALD0NTRED7p65+YXsJWWdg1wArGPxXJ0DbVXIAGwbfV0puLqShsamAOYQYF4BcJBcTmrIABTAmEqO3zFDlBo0AAlGoAHw4RiXEyETBvL6KJQAOhgoCInzhqghCIwSOIalU6mIwL0BGAZQxilBeAIBGhpnqm3hmCRjL6pNp5I+bMaRGpjFpyDYYAoUGKmhxMSR0tu90ez0pyiOvOB50FEgFQruovFOLVp0Ywp1yB04joQA)

```js
interface Item {
  id: number;
  parentId: number | null;
}

type Items = Item[];

const exampleItems: Items = [
  // Root element
  { id: 1, parentId: null },

  // Children of 1
  { id: 2, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 3, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 4, parentId: 1 },

  // Children of 3
  { id: 5, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 6, parentId: 3 }
];

const getRelated: Items = (items: Items, id: number) => {
  const item = items.find(item => item.id === id);

  if (item) {
    const parentId = item.parentId;

    if (parentId) {
      return [item, ...getRelated(items, parentId)];
    }

    return [item];
  }

  return [];
};
```

Comment: You are typing the function itself as `Items` and not the return type, move `Items` after the parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you type a `const` function. What you wrote translates to "I want a const variable named `getRelated` with type `Items`" and then follow to assign it a function as value. That's what the exception tells you.

What you probably want is

```
const getRelated = (items: Items, id: number): Items => {
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnLAAmAXMiAK4YBG0A3PsgA5xQTiqnlW1TIA+3ADZCGAX1y4wATyYp0EDAGdkAXjSYA2gF0GuBAHsQSsMggAPOBiZCIC5WXsr1mxgHo3yAEoGDpiLYY7GCM2IRcAIwANMyswZxklCLIYlGSBB7IAMIAFsBCRGwgyAYwyBGh4WQATDEsRWAJ5SlpBGHEZADMdXEckS2VHcgALD0NTRED7p65+YXsJWWdg1wArGPxXJ0DbVXIAGwbfV0puLqShsamAOYQYF4BcJBEasgAFMCYSo5fMUOUNGgAEofopnAA+HCMS4mQiYV6fMEAOhgoCIH3hqkhiIwSOIalU6mIQL0BGAZQxiiBUIIBBhpnqmwRmCRjL6pNp5PebMaRGpeFptLYYAoUGKmhxMSR0tu90ez0pyiOvKB50FEkYBGFovFOLVp0Y2rFyB04joQA)

Comment: I have look at this for too long. Shame on me, that was stupid. Thank you!

Comment: @MateuszJagiełło Don't worry, we all do this :) I usually take a break and a few hours later clarity follows.